# How to measure the length of a string form an integer before creating it

Tags: c++, c++11

I got a list of numbers (`int` and `double`s) which I need to export to a buffer as strings. The buffer has to be reserved beforehand. For speed and size reasons I do not want to create the strings, measure its size and then create it again into the buffer. And no, the used system does not allow to create the whole string and copy it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

For integers, you'll need `floor(log10(number)) + 1` decimal digits (adjusted for 0 and sign as necessary).

For doubles, the situation is a bit more complicated - it really depends on how you want to represent them. Most importantly, do you mind trailing `0`s after the decimal point? Is scientific notation an option?

One way to approach this would be: you need [17 decimal digits after the decimal point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) to represent an IEEE `double` in a string so that it can be reconstructed unambiguously. So always reserve those 17 digits, plus the period, and use the integer formula above for the integral part.